# JQuery Alertify confirm dialog box not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert, alertify

I am using <kbd>[Alertify](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/)</kbd> JQuery Plugin, to display <kbd>`alert,confirm, dialog`</kbd> box.

Problem am facing for confirmation, it not work correctly on ok or cancel click

**[Sample JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/)**

**JS Code:**

```
function myconfrm() {
 var falgset = true;
 alertify.confirm("Are you  sure to delete this record.", function (e) {
  if (e) {
          // user clicked "ok"
           falgset = false;
         }
    });
   alert(falgset);
   return falgset;
}

 $("#btn").live('click', function (event) {
                if (myconfrm()) {
                     // my ajax call 
           }
});
```

Comment: Just wondering: I noticed that your `Alertify` (the word at the top) looks cool. How do you do that?

Comment: @Jean-Paul: i used kbd tag for that effect,

Comment: @Homam: i have updated my question with JS fiddledemo

Comment: @downvoter: can you tell me, why u downvote, cmt pls

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how i solved
**[JS Fiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6zNaP/6/)**

```
 $("#btn").live("click", function () {
     alertify.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete?", function (asc) {
         if (asc) {
             //ajax call for delete       
             alertify.success("Record is deleted.");

         } else {
             alertify.error("You've clicked cancel");
         }
     }, "Default Value");
 });
```